# Using negative margins % to stack elements on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Been trying to get the lines to show stacked and occupying the full width of the parent, but something is offsetting the subsequent lines, only the first line (aligned to bottom) shows up properly:

```css
.sp-line{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000;
}
.sp_baseline{
  border-color: blue;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.sp_text-bottom{
  border-color: green;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.sp_bottom{
  border-color: red;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.sp_text-top{
  border-color: green;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.line{
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}

span.text {
  background-color: papayawhip;
  line-height: 1.96; 
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="sp-line sp_bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_baseline"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-top"></span>
  <span class="text1 text">SINGLE line</span>
</div>
```

Trying to get to:

[image]

I was just trying to recreate the lines from https://christopheraue.net/design/vertical-align I don't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Hi. do you have a image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you have a line-height, that will offset the % reduction from the negative margins.

Comment: I don't think changing the line-height/removing it changes things much? I just tried it

Comment: The lines are offset from the left side because the span elements each have a small width and are positioned left-to-right in the order they occur inside the div. I think you have to position them using ```position: absolute;```, but that breaks ```vertical-align```...

Comment: if I may, what's the issue here, things look okay to me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgjPKz

Comment: I wanted to have the dotted lines aligned to start from the beginning of the div

Comment: Why don't you use something like this inside your div.line?https://jsfiddle.net/4sn06p13/

Answer (score 1):

No need to make the element `width:100%` and use negative margin. Instead you can keep the element small to have them in one line and rely on overflow to have the dotted lines cover all the area:

```css
.line {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.sp-line{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.sp-line:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-top: 1px dotted;
  bottom:0;
  left:-100vw; /*big value here*/
  right:-100vw;/*big value here*/
}
.sp_baseline{
  color: blue;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.sp_text-bottom{
  color: green;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.sp_bottom{
  color: purple;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.sp_top{
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  transform:translateY(1px); /*we move the top one by 1px so we can see it*/
}
.sp_text-top{
  color: green;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

span.text {
  background-color: papayawhip;
  line-height: 1.96; 
  font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="text1 text">SINGLE line</span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_top"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_baseline"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-top"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you're experiencing has something to do with the width of 100% on your sp-class. It needs to take into account the border on the .line class (cyan outline), and some spacing on the font. I've set the width to calculate it at 100% less 4px to cater for this:

```css
.sp-line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  margin-right: -100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000;
}

.sp_baseline {
  border-color: blue;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.sp_text-bottom {
  border-color: green;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.sp_bottom {
  border-color: red;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.sp_text-top {
  border-color: green;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.line {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}

span.text {
  background-color: papayawhip;
  line-height: 1.96;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="sp-line sp_bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_baseline"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-bottom"></span>
  <span class="sp-line sp_text-top"></span>
  <span class="text1 text">SINGLE line</span>
</div>
```